# Selecting different rows in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have two functions and a table with 2 rows. I want one function to select the first row and the other function to select the second row. I am a bit lost because I am very new to LINQ.

Here is my current code:

```
    public static bool First() {
        using (Entities db = new Entities()) {
            DateTime FirstValue = (
                from a in db.Table
                select a.Timestamp
            ).Single();


    public static bool Second() {              
        using (Entities db = new Entities()) {
            DateTime SecondValue = (
                from a in db.Table
                select a.Timestamp
            ).Single();
```

I working with someone else's code and Im new to LINQ so I'm not sure what Single() does as well. I feel as though I do not need it in my code but I am not sure.

Comment: All `Single` does is give you one record.  Kind of like a `LIMIT 1` or `TOP 1` in `SQL`.  But it will throw an error if it doesnt get a record back.

Comment: I feel as though both my functions will give me the first row in the table

Comment: Doesnt look to me like there is any difference.  Is there anything other than timestamp in the table to differentiate them?

Comment: @paqogomez i just figured out my problem..it's been a long day...

Comment: The Skip idea that dkackman posted is a good one if you always want to get the second row, but as databases can serve things up in any order unless ordered, perhaps you want to query with where. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overwhelmed with LINQ that i should simply use a 'where' statement to locate something in my query...maybe I need a break

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
public static bool First() {
    using (Entities db = new Entities()) {
        DateTime FirstValue = (
            from a in db.Table
            select a.Timestamp
        ).FirstOrDefault();


public static bool Second() {              
    using (Entities db = new Entities()) {
        DateTime SecondValue = (
            from a in db.Table
            select a.Timestamp
        ).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I simply put a 'where' a.Id == (int). I was intimidated by LINQ since it was my first time using it but I got the idea =D

Answer (score 3):

@dkackman provided correct answer (use First/FirstOrDefault and Skip methods), but I want to mention that you can avoid mixing query syntax and method syntax, and methods could be simplified to:

```
public static DateTime First() 
{
    return GetByIndex(0);
}

public static DateTime Second() 
{
    return GetByIndex(1);
}

public static DateTime GetByIndex(int index)
{
    using (Entities db = new Entities())
       return db.Table.Select(a => a.TimeStamp).Skip(index).First();        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
private void First()
{
    using (WinEntitie obj = new WinEntitie())
    {
        var FirstValue = (from a in obj.Employees select a.EmpName).Take(1);
    }
}
private void Sec()
{
    using (WinEntitie obj = new WinEntitie())
    {
        var FirstValue = (from a in obj.Employees orderby a.EmpID ascending select a.EmpName ).Skip(1).First();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use common method for like this one what ever value you want to skip just pass it to the index. and also use the **FirstOrDefault** because the corresponding value returns null means it will take care or otherwise getting execption.

```
public static DateTime GetByIndex(int index)
{
    using (Entities db = new Entities()) {
       return db.Table.Select(a => a.TimeStamp).Skip(index).FirstOrDefault();        
    }
  return null;
}
```